# powershell formatting of a date stored as int64

Tags: powershell

I'm am trying to get a list of the users in my AD Domain along with their password expiration. I have this so far in PowerShell:

```
get-aduser -filter * -properties "msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed" | select name,samaccountname,@{Name="Expiry";Expression="msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed"}
```

Which results in something like this:

```
name                       samaccountname                                Expiry
----                       --------------                                ------
longneck                   longneck                          129802700808178073
```

How can I convert that Expiry column to a datetime? I've tried this:

```
get-aduser -filter * -properties "msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed" | select name,samaccountname,@{Name="Expiry";Expression={[datetime]::FromFileTime("msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed")}}
```

But that just results in a blank Expiry column.

```
name                       samaccountname                                Expiry
----                       --------------                                ------
longneck                   longneck
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the `$_` to indicate *which* object's `msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed` attribute to use in your expression.   The `$_` variable is the default current object in the pipeline.  You would find the value in `$_."msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed"`.

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties "msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed" | 
  Select-Object name,samaccountname,@{Name="Expry";Expression={[datetime]::FromFileTime($_."msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed")}}
```